# how to restrict the specific product in the cart page that should not allowed to specific country?

Tags: magento-1.9, shipping-methods

this should be done in the Web Shop Apps Matrix Rate – #1 Multiple Table Rates Extension.the product added in the cart page ,and only the specific product should
be allowed to certain country.and restricted for some country.this should be done only by using the above extension.

Answer (score 2):

You can add observer event `checkout_cart_product_add_before` and inside the observer function you may prevent product to adding cart.throw an exception if customer is from country you do not want to allow them to add product.

Comment: But i need to restrict to both customer and guest.

Comment: If you can anyway the country of guest then you can restrict them too.you can get the country of guest probably from billing address.

Comment: Use owebia shipping extensions open-source

Comment: can you help me regard Matrix rate https://magento.stackexchange.com/q/241323/39050 @Meenakshi